# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (AT&T) bricked while trying to root

Tags: rooting, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

While trying to root Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (SM-T337A), it now says

> System software not authorized by ATT has been found on your phone

Downloading the firmware through Odin didn't help.

Aside from taking it to the nearest AT&T or Best Buy, is there a way to fix this by myself?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to download your original STOCK rom and flash it through odin.

I need more info about your question. When you rooted it, did it sucessfully root? Do you know if the bootloader is unlocked?

Also, what kind of recovery are you using?

Comment: It rooted successfully but the bootloader is unlocked and I downloaded the file from sammobile and went through Odin 3.12 but it failed

Comment: Did you use a .pit file when flashing? Flashing with odin requires a pit file.                                                The PIT file tells Odin where to correctly place the files when flashing. It probably didn't work since you didn't use a pit file.

Comment: No where do I find the PIT file

Comment: You can get the PIT file right from the internet. To correctly search for your devices PIT file, google search: Galaxy Tab 4 (Model Number) PIT download.

Comment: I hope its not too much to ask but can you list the exact steps i have to take for the whole process i want to make sure im doing it right

Comment: Sure! I will post another answer. Give me a sec :) Also, can you tell me that model your galaxy tab 4 is?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Download correct (Stock) rom off the internet. Make sure it is the STOCK rom, and that is matches your model number.

Step 2: Make sure you have obtained the correct PIT file for your galaxy tab 4.

Step 3: Once you have the files, don't plug your tab into the computer just yet.

Step 4: Before you plug your galaxy tab into the computer, make sure you have the samsung drivers installed on the computer. The drivers is essential for successful flashing!

Step 5: Once the drivers are installed, you are ready to go! Plug your tab into the computer and odin SHOULD detect the galaxy tab. It should look like this:[image: DETECTED]

Step 6: Place the PIT file you downloaded in the pit section (Click PIT and then choose your PIT file).

Step 7: Now it's time to install your rom! Click on the option: "PDA", and pick the rom (It should be in a zip), that you downloaded. ALSO, do NOT check re-partion!!!!!!! You can choose auto-reboot option if you would like.

Step 8: Now click start, and the installation should take about 3-5 minutes depending on the size of the rom you downloaded.

Step 9: If it was successful, you SHOULD see a bold green box that say's PASS!

If NOT successful, Let me know!

Comment: I downloaded the pit fil but it wont pop up when i go to put it into odin I have model sm-t337a

Comment: Did you try searching in the "Download" tab? Could you possible send a picture?

Comment: I cant send pictures but i downloaded the pit file and i extracted it. the files will pop up when im just in my files but they wont when i try to put it in odin

Comment: That's odd. Close Odin and then open it and see what that does.

Comment: it did the same thing. I dont even know if i downloaded the right file. I tried googling it but there was barely anything on the PIT file for sm-t337a

Comment: I will try to find the pit file for you :)

Comment: I can't seem to find it. But according to one website, you don't have to use a pit file if you don't want to re-partion. Try without the PIT file. If that doesn't work, show me the link of where you download the ROM.

Comment: the only things i downloaded was the firmware from sammobile and odin where do i get the ROM

Comment: Have you been to this link? https://samsung-firmware.org/download/Galaxy-Tab-4-8.0-LTE-(AT%26T)/27a9/ATT/T337AUCU1ANF4/T337AATT1ANF4/          if so, let me know. If not, download rom from that site and try it.

Comment: no i havent but im gonna try from there

Comment: okay so when i try on odin it fails and on my tablet at the top it says SW REV CHECK FAIL: [aboot] Fused 2> binary 1

Comment: Wait, did you ever boot into download mode?

Comment: thats when u hold the power+ volume down + home button yes I did